# Just what kind of transformations can TransformedDistribution handle?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

Why does the following command return an empty plot?

```
Plot[PDF[TransformedDistribution[(2 Z - 1) X, 
{Distributed[X, ExponentialDistribution[1]], 
Distributed[Z, BernoulliDistribution[0.5]]}], t], {t, -1, 1}]
```

Yet `RandomVariate` works just fine:

```
SmoothHistogram@RandomVariate[TransformedDistribution[(2 Z - 1) Abs[X], 
{Distributed[X, ExponentialDistribution[1]], 
Distributed[Z, BernoulliDistribution[0.5]]}], 1.*^5]
```

I merely give a particular example; don't focus unduly on it, I want to generalize.

Comment: Have you checked that the function `PDF[...]` actually returns values ?

Comment: `TransformedDistribution` doesn't seem to like products of distributions, or the mixture of Exponential and Bernoulli,

Comment: This *is* a continuous distribution (the [Laplace or Double Exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution)), so that's not the problem.  A little testing with simpler expressions suggests `TransformedDistribution` isn't anything more than a toy at this point: it can take a large amount of computation to obtain simple sums (such as adding an Exponential to a Gamma variate), if it succeeds at all, and simply fails quietly when evaluating most multivariate expressions.

Comment: My answer is no longer an answer to your question since your edits, so I have deleted it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TransformedDistribution` contains a collection of identities known to it, like that of sum of normals being equal in distribution to another normal random variable, and a general machinery to work out properties of the functions of random variables.

Most of the time the computation will be done by the general machinery, which relies on solvers, like `Expectation` and `Probability`. Hence `TransformedDistribution` will be as strong as those are.

The major strength of `TransformedDistribution`, in my opinion, is that it allows for easy and efficient sampling. It is generally expensive to work out other properties of the random variable from this representation.

In this particular example of $(2 Z-1) X \stackrel{d}{=} -(-1)^Z X$ the underlying solvers did not know how to handle the mixed case of discrete and continuous distribution:

```
In[11]:= di = 
  TransformedDistribution[(2 z - 1) x, {z \[Distributed] 
     BernoulliDistribution[1/2], 
    x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]}];

In[12]:= CDF[di, z]

Out[12]= CDF[
 TransformedDistribution[(-1 + 
     2 \[FormalX]1) \[FormalX]2, {\[FormalX]1 \[Distributed] 
    BernoulliDistribution[1/2], \[FormalX]2 \[Distributed] 
    ExponentialDistribution[1]}], z]
```

As it is often the case, one can work out the answer in an alternative way:

```
In[13]:= CharacteristicFunction[di, t] // Simplify

Out[13]= 1/(1 + t^2)

In[14]:= pdf = 
 InverseFourierTransform[%, t, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]

Out[14]= 1/2 E^-Abs[x]
```