# Reflecting the Polya-Aeppli distribution

Tags: graphs-and-networks, distributions

How would I go about reflecting the [Polya-Aeppli distribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolyaAeppliDistribution.html) in *Mathematica* about a y-axis (switching left and right) while keeping the command. The distribution will not allow negative parameters for k or theta. The main thing is I need a distribution with exactly the same properties, except the tail becomes skewed left instead of right. It just would be really convenient to keep the same command.

Comment: How about `TransformedDistribution[-x, x \[Distributed] PolyaAeppliDistribution[θ, p]]`?

Comment: Thank you. The documentation agrees, but I'll have to figure out how to plot it. I'm going to try to extend on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/just-what-kind-of-transformations-can-transformeddistribution-handle, but this is very new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I've understand your question, but if you just need the reflected plot, you can try:

```
With[{θ = 7, p = 1/4, m = -35}, 
      DiscretePlot[PDF[PolyaAeppliDistribution[θ, p], -x], {x, m, 0}]]
```

[image]

The method suggested by @Rahul Narain is also available:

```
With[{θ = 7, p = 1/4, m = -35}, 
 DiscretePlot[PDF[TransformedDistribution[-y, 
    y \[Distributed] PolyaAeppliDistribution[θ, p]], x], {x, m, 0}]]
(* The plot is same as the former so let me omit it. *)
```