# Why I need Evaluate for the Plot of the probability density function of PolyaAeppliDistribution?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I encountered this when I was trying to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40204/1871). I just can't understand why the following code will only give a line at $y=0$:

```
Plot[PDF[PolyaAeppliDistribution[7, 1/4], x], {x, 0, 35}, Axes -> {False, True}]
```

[image]

While with `Evaluate` I'll get the desired result:

```
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[PolyaAeppliDistribution[7, 1/4], x], {x, 0, 35}]
```

[image]

`DiscretePlot`, which is a function with `Attributes` similar to `Plot`, doesn't suffer this:

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[PolyaAeppliDistribution[7, 1/4], x], {x, 0, 35}]
```

[image]

nor do many other distributions, for example `NormalDistribution`:

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[7, 2], x], {x, 0, 35}]
```

[image]

I haven't do a complete test so I'm not sure if there's other distribution behaved like `PolyaAeppliDistribution`. Has it got any deep reasons? Or it's just a bug?

I'm using *Mathematica 8*, *Windows Vista Home Basic 32-bit*.

Comment: Same behavior in 9.0.1 on Win7.

Comment: You'll get the same result with other non-continuous distributions. Use `DiscretePlot`.

Comment: @rasher Oh, I see! Why not give an answer?

Comment: @xzczd: Are you requesting I put the comment as an answer? I'll assume so and do so, if not let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: @rasher Yeah, just enlarge it into an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rasher mentioned, it's all because `PolyaAeppliDistribution` is a discrete distribution.

The `PDF` of non-continuous distributions only have non-zero values at discrete points. Still choose the `PolyaAeppliDistribution` as the example:

```
ListPlot[PDF[PolyaAeppliDistribution[7, 1/4], #] & /@ Range[0, 35, 1/10]]
```

[image]

The plot showing up when evaluating the `PDF` isn't that of the `PDF` of `PolyaAeppliDistribution` at all. In fact the expression is no longer a discrete function after evaluated:

```
PDF[PolyaAeppliDistribution[7, 1/4], x]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{1/E^7, x == 0}, {(21 Hypergeometric1F1[1 - x, 2, -21])/(4^x*E^7), x > 0}}, 0]
> ```

[Hypergeometric1F1](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hypergeometric1F1.html) is continuous.

Answer (score 5):

You'll get the same result with other non-continuous distributions. Use `DiscretePlot`.

You can observe that the under-the-covers behavior is different when you evaluate the `PDF` (use `EvaluationMonitor`), many more points are sampled. The plot showing up is a side-effect I've not investigated enough to explain. You can also set `WorkingPrecision` to 1, and you'll get a (rough) plot, since MM is basically forced into using values that actually have `PDF` values. In any case, `Plot` is not appropriate for non-continuous distribution `PDF`, just use `DiscretePlot` with `Joined->True`.

Comment: The `WorkingPrecision -> 1` method is interesting! And I take the liberty to add some further exploration to your answer, feel free to undo it if you don't like it.

Comment: @xzczd: I'd rather you just post it as your own answer and accept it, completely re-writing someone else's answer in this way is... yes, please just post it as your own, feel free to use anything from my original answer, that's fine by me.

Comment: Undone. Sorry, I seemed to be a little excited 囧.

Comment: @xzczd: No worries!